# Add a new div on button click and option to select an option to show textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, mysql

I have this project am working on. The second stage of customer orders, the orders has to be splitted for multiple orders.

On each new div, if the add another suborder button is clicked, the user can upload sample material, enter customer's requirement, and answer a question if he/she has a style code available and if so, select from the option and enter the code in the textbox that will appear and this will be possible for every suborders.

I've been working on it since yesterday, almost 1 full day already. I've achieved the add suborder button, it works, but in each suborder, the i have a style code will not display the needed textbox in that suborder but only at the first suborder, please am not good with Javascript, i need help in fixing that and also how to get the array of suborders and post them into my php variable for submission to the database. I figure that the name fields has to incremented by javascript somehow, so as to uniquely identify each field, please someone help me, am completely lost on how to move forward.

Below are my codes;

```
<script>
  function showfield(name){
    if(name=='style[]')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<label>Enter Style Code</label><br /> <input type="text" name="style[]" />';
    else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".form-group"); //Fields wrapper
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
          e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top:20px; border-top:1px solid #333333;"><label>Upload Sample Material</label><br /><input type="file" name="staff_passport" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/><label>Customer&#39s Requirement</label><br /><textarea name="cust_requirement" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/><label>Do you have a style</label><br /><select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"><option value="style[]">I have a style code</option><option value="">I don&#39t have a style code</option></select><div id="div1"></div><br /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
              }
            });
        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove  text
          e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
      });
    </script>

    <form action="orderadd2.php" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="add_field_button">Add another sub-order</button>
        <div style="margin-top:20px;">
          <label>Upload Sample Material</label><br />
          <input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/>
          <label>Customer's Requirement</label><br />
          <textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/>
          <label>Do you have a style</label><br />
          <select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value="">I don't have a style code</option>
            <option value="style[]">I have a style code</option>
          </select>
          <div id="div1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-block" value="ADD">
    </form>
```

Thank you so much for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change your code you can do that easily using jquery replace your code with this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function showfield(name,event){

  if(name=='iHaveStyle') {
    $(event).next('#div1').html('<label>Enter Style Code</label><br /> <input type="text" name="style[]" />');
  } else{
     $(event).next('#div1').html('');
  }

  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".form-group"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
      e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div style="margin-top:20px; border-top:1px solid #333333;"><label>Upload Sample Material</label><br /><input type="file" name="staff_passport[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/><label>Customer&#39s Requirement</label><br /><textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/><label>Do you have a style</label><br /><select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)"><option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option><option value="">I don&#39t have a style code</option></select><div id="div1"></div><br /><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
          }
        });
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove  text
      e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
  });
</script>

<form action="orderadd2.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add another sub-order</button>
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">
      <label>Upload Sample Material</label><br />
      <input type="file" name="sample_material[]" style="width:200px; height: 40px;" /><br/><br/>
      <label>Customer's Requirement</label><br />
      <textarea name="cust_requirement[]" style="width:200px; height: 150px;" /></textarea><br/><br/>
      <label>Do you have a style</label><br />
      <select name="sketch_code" id="sketch_code" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this)">
        <option value="">I don't have a style code</option>
        <option value="iHaveStyle">I have a style code</option>
      </select>
      <div id="div1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-color btn-block" value="ADD">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of stress.